# Problem with babel

Tags: babel, french

I can't understand the way babel works (or, more precisely, doesn't) in the following example. The command \sujet is supposed to create a new command named \sujeti, which in turn is supposed to print the 4th argument of \sujet.

This seems to be quite the case **except** that
1) the punctuation, which should be French thanks to babel, is wrong (no space before '!');
2) there is no way to use the \verb command in the content of \sujet.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\RequirePackage[french]{babel}

\newcommand\addindex[4][]{% #2 as name of var, #3 as index and #4 as content
  \csname#1def\expandafter\endcsname\csname #2\roman{#3}\endcsname{#4}%
}

\newcounter{num_sujet}

\newcommand{\sujet}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{num_sujet}
    \addindex{sujet}{num_sujet}{#1\par} 
    \par   
}

\sujet{%
    Test! %\verb/there should be a space before '!', and \verb doesn't seem to work/
}

\begin{document}
    \sujeti
\end{document}
```

Any help or explanation on what is going on would be very welcome.

Comment: babel sets up the special settings at `\begin{docuemnt]` so the `!` in the preamble will not be active and get french spacing

Comment: unrelated buut your `\newccommand{\sujet}` definition is missing two `%` as it is it adds two space tokens each time it is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `babel` does not make its shorthand active in the preamble to prevent that the loading of other packages is disturbed. The macros `\shorthandon` and `shorthandoff` can activate and deactivate the shorthand for the text in the preamble. The following example simplifies the original MWE to show the point more clearly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\RequirePackage[french]{babel}

\newcommand{\sujet}[1]{%
    \def\sujeti{#1}%
}

\shorthandon{!}
\sujet{Test!}
\shorthandoff{!}

\begin{document}
    \sujeti
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]